# Is there a way to list all the images of directory and read one at a time?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to list all the images of a directory and read one at a time. The directory location will be given from a input field.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// on below line we are creating variable for image view.
ImageView imageIV;
Button viewButton;
EditText inputFolder;
HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView;
TextView textView1;
String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   viewButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.viewButton);
   horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
   inputFolder = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputFolder);

   viewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           inputFolder = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputFolder);
           textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           textView1.setText(inputFolder.getText().toString());
       }
   });

    // on below line we are creating an image file and
    // specifying path for the image file on below line.
    name = inputFolder.getText().toString();
    File imgFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20220912-174402.jpg");

    // on below line we are initializing variables with ids.
    imageIV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.idIVImage);

    // on below line we are checking if the image file exist or not.
    if (imgFile.exists()) {
        // on below line we are creating an image bitmap variable
        // and adding a bitmap to it from image file.
        Bitmap imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        // on below line we are setting bitmap to our image view.
        imageIV.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
    }
}
```

}

I am using above code for the same, but unable to feed output of the input field to list all the image files.

Comment: Well tell what you see with:  Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName())

Comment: `inputFolder = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputFolder);` Thyat makes no sense if you come here for help as we do not see what is typed in. Better just hard code someting.